# Installing GD php module on redhat 5.8 x64

Tags: php, module, gd, redhat

```
[root@abc php-5.3.25]$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/php-5.3.25 --enable-fpm --
sysconfdir=/etc/php5 --with-config-file-path=/etc/php5
```

**configure: error: config-file-path: invalid package name**

how fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it through up2date:

```
up2date --install php-gd
```